# Assosiative array, assosiation names as first array index

Tags: php, associative-array

I am trying to get the assosiation names of my array into the first index of the array without having to repeat the 50 "columns"
Is that possibles. I was looking at 
array_combine, array_merge, array_fill_keys.
But somehow that does seem to be the way I would want it. I can´t find the right function.

**Array example:**

```
loop some queryresult

    $array1 = array(
        "a" => $first,
        "b" => $second,
        "c" => $third
    }
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [a] => a,
        [b] => b,
        [c] => c
    ),
    [1] => Array(
        [a] => first,
        [b] => second,
        [c] => third
    ),
```

Comment: Is `array_keys()` an option for you?

Comment: You wouldn't need to loop twice. During each time through the loop, just push the key onto the first array element and the value onto the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily accomplished using `array_keys()` and `array_combine()`:

```
$input = array(
    'a' => 'first',
    'b' => 'second',
    'c' => 'third',
);

$output = array(
    array_combine(array_keys($input), array_keys($input)),
    $input,
);
```

Read about [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

Comment: This solution is more elegant than the other one. However it creates one additional copy of the array of keys and passes three arrays as arguments to API functions instead of one. No problem with small arrays, but this should be considered when very large arrays are handled. Would be interesting to see memory and runtime characteristics with varying array sizes...

Answer (score 0):

There's no way without iterating over the array keys.

```
$output = array(array(), $array1);
foreach(array_keys($array1) as $key)
    $output[0][$key] = $key;
```